# How to handle magic variables in a constructor of a Class

Tags: python, oop, args

I need a `magic variable` in my class and started writing it

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        ????

    def myFunc()
        for i in args:
            print(i)
```

I just could not find a proper explanation of how to write a class with magic variables in the constructor and use it later. Do I have to create a `self.` member out of it (and if so how) or can I neglect it and just use args as in `myFunc` ?

Comment: How does `myFunc` relate to `myclass`?

Comment: @NChauhan Okay he edited it

Comment: Sorry, messed up indentation. Correction done

Comment: What do you mean by "magic variable"? The "*args" are variadic arguments, which gives you a regular tuple. You can just assign it to a name.

Comment: Sorry, but your questions is unclear to me, it would be a big help if you could make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I picked up a wrong definition? A friend teached me that *args and *kwargs are called magic variables. I just wanted to know how I can create a self. variable out of an unspecified (depending on the number of arguments) argument like *args. But Chauhan provided a sufficiant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` are not called magic variables, but [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), or `variadic arguments`, and they are used to send arbitrary number of arguments to a function, and they are wrapped in a tuple like the example below

```
In [9]: def f(a,*args): 
   ...:     print(a) 
   ...:     print(args) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                           

In [10]: f(1,2,3,4)                                                                                                                                                               
1
(2, 3, 4)
```

So in order to access these variables, you would do what you do for any class instance variable, assign it via `self.args = args` and access them via `self.args`

Also note that we use `camel-case` for class names, so the class name changes to `MyClass` and `snake-case` for functions, so the function name changes to `my_func`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        #Assigning variadic arguments using self
        self.args = args

    def my_func(self):
        #Accessing variadic arguments  using self
        for i in self.args:
            print(i)


obj = MyClass('Joe',1,2,3)
obj.my_func()
```

The output will be

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the `args` to `self.args`, you can access them from other methods. However this method must accept the instance of the class as its first argument (see below how `myFunc` takes `self` now).

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.args = args

    def myFunc(self):
        for i in self.args:
            print(i)
```